# Generic interface has too many types, pattern to reduce?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, design-principles

I can't find the right pattern for this design.

I have an interface that has some methods. All of these methods need to be generic because these types can differ in every implementation of the interface. The purposes of these methods are the same but the return types and parameters are different. Imagine it like every service uses an adapter to handle the requests and responses. The methods in these adapters are the same but the types of requests and responses can vary.

The naive implementation can be found below. The main problem with it is that this interface uses way too many types. You could tell that I might break it down into smaller interfaces and smaller adapters but those would increase the number of dependencies where I would use these features.

What would be the ideal pattern to lower the number of generic types?

```java
interface ProductAdapter<A, B, C, D, E, F, G> {
  
  B create(A param);

  D read(C param);

  F update(E param)

  void delete(F param);
}
```

```java
class StoreProductAdapter implements Adapter<StoreProductCreateRequest, StoreProductCreateResponse,
StoreProductUpdateRequest, StoreProductUpdateResponse,
StoreProductReadRequest, StoreProductReadResponse,
StoreProductDeleteRequest> {
  
  @Override
  public StoreProductCreateResponse create(StroreProductCreateRequest request) {
    return null;
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public void delete(StoreProductDeleteRequest request) {
    ...
  }
}
```

```java
class StoreProductController{

  private StoreProductAdapter StoreProductAdapter;

  //CRUD methods as well.
  
}
```

Comment: My first though is you likely have a service method that's trying to do too much.  You might be better off breaking up the code into multiple services.

Comment: You've stated the question in such an abstract fashion, there is no possible answer to it. That doesn't mean your stuck with your current design - just that any insights about how to refactor it require domain knowledge. Surely it's not really `MyAdapter`, it's, I dunno, `StorefrontItemAdapter` or some such. Maybe if you edit the question and explain how all these things are supposed to relate, there are answers available.

Comment: But, yes, if you just want a generalized answer: Hey, if you write 1 interface whose implementations do 6 things that are mostly independent and very lightly related to each other, you end up with 6 type params. That's.. what happens then. Split it up into separate interfaces would be advised (this then leads to 'oof, now my classes implement 6 interfaces!' - that's a separate question :P)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find a less abstract way to show the problem.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I tried to refactor it, maybe it is more understanable

Comment: Why do you need to create this many Request and Response types, you should have generic interface for IRequest, IResponse, **no** need to create IStoreProductCreateRequest and so on. Learn it from existing java/C# frameworks/libraries

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Controller has a given interface that I cannot modify. By implementing that interface, I have to use those types. Sadly, it is not my decision. By the way, I agree with you it shouldn't use that many types.

Comment: Is the `ProductAdapter` interface going to have 1-2 generic implementations, or is it going to have 1 implementation per controller? It looks like it's the latter, in which case this interface doesn't seem useful to begin with.